# Why vim session file doesn't save the modified vimrc file

Tags: vim

I normally edit my vimrc file inside the vim with my current session file.

```
mksession
```

I did use

```
:mk!  /mysession.vim
```

to save my current file before I exit vim.

I reload mysession.vim with

```
vim  -S /mysession.vim
```

I don't find my vimrc takes effort

Comment: The session saves all of the current settings and restores them. `-S` loads the file after the first file is read so your vimrc is already loaded and then the session restores the old values.

Comment: how can  you use current session file to use the newly vimrc file

Comment: You can resource the vimrc manually. Most times that just works.

Comment: I think this answer: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5371/19554 answers your question.  I find I have to use
`vim -S ~/.vim/sessions/mysession.vim -S ~/.vim/vimrc`
which is just another way of doing the same thing in the linked answer.